# Moving blob that triggered Azure function from "sub folder" to "sub folder"

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, prefix

So what is the best way to move a blog that triggered an azure function between "sub folders" in blob container. I know that Azure function blob containers are flat, so the thing i call sub folder to keep the context simple is in fact prefixes in the blob URI.

But lets say my function app fetches a blob ("my blob") from my blob inbound "sub folder".

```cs
public void Run([BlobTrigger("%InbloundBlobStoragePath%/{name}", Connection = "ConnectionString")] Stream myBlob, string name, ILogger log)
{
 //... Function Logic...
}
```

What is best practice here? I would guess it would involve to change the prefix of "myBlob", save it with a new prefix, and delete the original one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well in my case i think i was on the right track, this worked for me:

First declaring the "BlobContainerClient" in my constructor:

```cs
private BlobContainerClient _blobContainerClient;

public Function()
{
   _blobContainerClient = new BlobContainerClient(ConnectionString, BlobStorageContainer);
}
```

And then just uploading the "myBlob" stream with a new "{prefix}/" + name,
there after delete the old blob using its original name and prefix as shown below.

```cs
_blobContainerClient.UploadBlob("processed/" + name, myBlob);
_blobContainerClient.DeleteBlob("inbound/" + name);
```